# PHP - multiple values in an object

Tags: php

I'm using the eBay API and the following works fine:

```
$request->itemFilter[] = new FTypes\ItemFilter([
   'name' => 'Seller',
   'value' => ['seller1'],
   'value' => ['seller2'],
]);
```

I have an array full of sellers, how can I populate the object with them?

For example this doesn't work:

```
$request->itemFilter[] = new FTypes\ItemFilter([
   'name' => 'Seller',

   foreach($sellers as $seller) {
     'value' => [$seller],
   }

]);
```

I get an unexpected foreach error.

Comment: you can't have a control-structure (foreach) inside an array-definition (`[]`)

Comment: and having twice the same key ('value') in one array also won't work!

Comment: seller2 override seller1 ?

Comment: so build the array first, then pass it to ItemFilter

Comment: @jeff you mean the key 'value' probably

Comment: @ikdekker sure....oops & thanks

Comment: Stab into the dark… `['name' => 'Seller', 'value' => $sellers]`…!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you given is not correct make it array like this

```
$request->itemFilter[] = new FTypes\ItemFilter([
   'name' => 'Seller',
   'value' => ['seller1','seller2'],
]);
```

And you can make it with,

Untill you need to get specific value from `$sellers` this loop is not necessary you can use `$sellers` directly

```
/* 
$value = array();
foreach($sellers as $seller) {
  $value[] = $seller;
}
*/
```

Or you can use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) ; to returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

```
$value = array_values($sellers);

$request->itemFilter[] = new FTypes\ItemFilter([
   'name' => 'Seller',
   'value' => $value,
]);
```

Comment: That loop is completely superfluous, it's just recreating the `$sellers` array. The only time it would do anything is if the keys weren't continuously numeric, in which case `array_values` would be more useful.